# Flexbox Combine Span and Table Columns (align only last column)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to take a table and style it as follows:

- Three columns, the first two columns act as span elements, the third element fills whatever space is left.
- All three elements should always stay on one line.
- The third element of each row should always all be the same width (so all should be the smallest width of any row (ie if the largest combined columns one and two on a row take up 25% of the space, all of the column 3 items on every row should take up 75% of the space).

I am pretty close with this, but the third column is not all aligned and the same width, pretty stuck on that one:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column nowrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

td:nth-child(1) {
  clear: both;
}

td:nth-child(1),
td:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

td:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>status</td>
    <td>string</td>
    <td>The delivery status of the send – either unknown, scheduled, softbounce, hardbounce, or delivered</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>status</td>
    <td>data_feed_url</td>
    <td>The delivery status of the send – either unknown, scheduled, softbounce, hardbounce, or delivered</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>status</td>
    <td>image</td>
    <td>The delivery status of the send – either unknown, scheduled, softbounce, hardbounce, or delivered</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Sidenote**: Due to constraints with Markdown, I am trying to avoid anything that would involve additional HTML tags.